# What javascript library/template engine to use in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, json

I have to make a invite your facebook friends module which fetches the names, photos of your friends and allows you to message 'em. I need this to look like a integral part of my website so I have to style it. I fetch the json with friends' ids, names etc. and want to put those values in certain html tags and attributes. How do I apporach this? I can make it in jQuery but want to avoid jQuery spaghetti code with ragu of strings and vars. What lib/template engine do you recommend me? Ease of use and weight are the most important things. The website has jQuery already included.

Answer (score 0):

> I can make it in jQuery but want to avoid jQuery spaghetti code with ragu of strings and vars. What lib/template engine do you recommend me?

I’d suggest to use *no* big additional lib or template engine – I’d just keep using jQuery, and embed one of the *sprintf for jQuery* implementations that are floating around the net.

So you can define your “HTML template” for your output in *one* location as *one* string, and than replace placeholders in that string with variable values while your looping over the data in jQuery.

If you don’t like any of the sprintf-Jquery-plugins out there, here is another very simple and short function that implements just the basic string placeholder %s (but more than that you most likely won’t need anyway): http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/10/11/simple-maintainable-templating-with-javascript/.

(And if you have to insert values in multiple places of your template string, than have a look at my comment on the bottom of that page, where if have proposed a simple adjustment to Nicolas’ function, that implements the “argument swapping” feature of PHP’s sprintf, so that you have to pass values to the function only once, but can use them in multiple places in your template string.)

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this is to use the [Requests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/). The first thing you need to do is create an app. Once you have this you should be able to use the JavaScript example on the request dialog page.